# Variable going back to zero in SSIS

Tags: c#, variables, ssis, key

I am new to ssis scripts, I am having some problems. In the `ProcessInputRow`I popped up a message confirming my `key` is equal to the `Row.KeyValue +1`, but when I use the message in the `CreateNewOutputRows` it is back to 0. I don't get why the key is changing back to 0 in a different function. What am I doing wrong? (This is a script component)

```
int count = 0;
int key;
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    count = count + 1;
    if (Variables.KeyValueRowCount == count)
    {
        key = Row.KeyValue + 1;
    }
}
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    base.CreateNewOutputRows();
    NewKeyBuffer.AddRow();
    NewKeyBuffer.NewKey = key;
}
```

Comment: Could you help me understand the intention of your script. I see it's an asynchronous script but want to ensure I understand the why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what's the reason, but one of the workarounds could be defining a package variable in SSIS, and accessing it by `Dts.Variables["key"].Value`.

Remember to put it as read/write variables in `Script Task`

Comment: Well I am assigning the key to a key variable in my PostExecute, but I thought you cannot assign a variable in the ProcessInputRow; I got an error last time I tried that.

Comment: You most definitely can assign values to variables (and row input columns, if they are set as input columns in the component) at any point in the script, since they are exposed to the namespace.